# How to get IDynamicMetaObjectProvider for a static (compile time) type?

Tags: c#-4.0, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime, linq-expressions

I want to execute dynamic expressions (provided by the user) in the context/scope of a compile time type. 
In the example below, context is an instance of an arbitrary compile time type. To create the scope for evaluation, I'd like to make use of the fact that all available properties and their types are known at compile time.

```
var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
var func = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("a + b").Compile();
var context = new { a = 1, b = 2 };
var scope = engine.CreateScope((IDynamicMetaObjectProvider)context); // Fails to compile
var result = func.Execute(scope);
context.a = 5;
var result2 = func.Execute(scope);
```

Solutions I don't want to take are:

1. Let context inherit from DynamicObject and overwrite GetMember (for performance reasons)
2. Add context to scope and change expression to "context.a + context.b" (for usability reasons)

I'm sure, there is already a mechanism for getting the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think that event if there were a way to generate a meta object provider for a class or there were a base implementation for CLR types providing the static members that wouldn't be a generally valid implementation for a IronPython scope. It is missing an dynamic extension mechanism (similar to ExpandoObject) for cases where new variables are added to the scope. Or would that be an actual feature for your use-case?

Comment: I only execute expressions, so I couldn't assign or add variables in scope. But thanks for pointing out that adding would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `DLR` automatically knows how to dynamically invoke members that are defined at compile time. In fact even if you have an actual implementation of `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` it will look for a statically defined members first before looking trying the dynamic meta object.

First, you don't need to (and also can't) cast a `plain old clr object` to `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` if it doesn't actually implement it.

Second, I think your confusion, about the python scope not seeing your object's members, is coming from the fact that you are using an `Anonymous Type`. `Anonymous Types` are marked as **internal**, thus your python scope doesn't have permission to see it's members and complains that it doesn't implement it. Use an actual defined object or an `ExpandoObject`. `ExpandoObjects` actually have crazy awesome performance for getting members (however not setting them), infact they have *better* get member performance than a `plain old clr object` accessed by the `DLR`.

The Following benchmark, shows the ExpandoObject getters run about 43% faster than the poco called by the DLR:

```
public class Poco{
    public int One {get;set;}
    public string Test {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var iterations =Math.Pow(10,8);

    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    expando.One =1;
    expando.Test = "Test";
    dynamic poco = new Poco{One =1, Test = "Test"};

    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++){
        var test1 = poco.One;
        var test2 = poco.Test;
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    var dlrPocoTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++){
        var test1 = expando.One;
        var test2 = expando.Test;
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    var expandoTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


    Console.WriteLine((double)dlrPocoTime/expandoTime);

}
```

Comment: I know that I can't cast poco to idmop (the compiler told me :-), but my question is how to implement an idmop for poco. The anonymous type was just used in the example. I could also use a real type.

Comment: Do you have some links or benchmarks for a performance comparison between ExpandoObject and poco?

Comment: You don't implement a IDMOP where all the members are know at compile time, the DLR doesn't need a DynamicMetaObject to call non dynamic members it just does it. I've also added a benchmark that you can run. On my machine DLR calls to getters on an ExpandoObject are 43% faster than DLR calls to a poco object.